# Adding a UIView based on a template in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I've used UITableView before and like the way that the user can add a practically unlimited number of cells by entering information and the program uses a template. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this, but instead of using a table, using regular views or even buttons. For example, the user would tap a button, enter information, and return to the first ViewController and it would have a new view with the information in place of parts of a template that I designed.

Sorry if this is unclear. Basically I'm wondering if there is a way to make a table that is not as restrictive as a table, but uses several individual views in place of cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can create re-usable views in the same way that you can create prototype cells.

Just right click in your project window, add new file and select User Interface > View. create it just like you would a prototype cell.

Then create a related class by adding a new swift file, link the two, create any outlets or actions you need and add any required logic.

Once you are done you can just load it wherever you need it, like so

```
self.headerView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HeaderView",owner:self,options:nil) as! HeaderView
```

You would likely need to pass in some required information, or setup the views frame or constraints.

I found a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5SKUXSuDOw) which should help guide you through the process. I've only skimmed through it so you may need to look around for a better one, but the general concept seems to be there.